# React JS open a modal on button press if a user is not logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a voting system like stackoverflow, when a user clicks a button to vote up / down, if he's not logged in, a pop-up modal is displayed.
My user information is stored in context so I can use a hook to check if I have currently sign in user. The question is how can  I properly make a check inside onClick handler.

My first suggestion was something like this.

```
function userVote(){

  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState();

  const auth = useAuth();

  const handleClick = () => !auth.user ? setShowModal(true) : "the logic for updating the user 
  vote if he is already signed in"

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}></button>
      {showModal ? <Modal /> : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

But as far as I know, it is not a good practice to make state updates inside conditions or I'm wrong. I suppose there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with updating the state in conditional statements. The bad thing is to update the state in effects (`useEffect`)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get rid of the condition before updating the state modify your function to be like:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setShowModal(!auth.user)
  if (auth.user) {
  // Write the logics here
  }
}
```

it sets the state no matter if `auth.user` exists or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).